# Как добавить имя функции из которой вызывается define без форматирования

Tags: c++, c

Есть такой код:

```
#define MESSAGE(c) #c": cannot access class member "__FUNCTION__"!"

int main()
{
cout << MESSAGE(CTrader);
}
```

Который не работает [error: unable to find string literal operator ‘operator""__ FUNCTION __’ with ‘const char [38]’, ‘long unsigned int’ arguments]

!(специально сделал отступ между нижними подчёркиваниями)

В консоли должно вывестись:
CTrader : cannot access class member main!
аргумент входящий в MESSAGE : имя функции из которого вызывается дефайн

Даже если добавить # перед __ FUNCTION __ то всё равно будут ошибки.

Как сделать так, чтобы через дефайн получалась строка, содержащая первый входящий аргумент (его псевдоним, например CTrader) и имя функции из которой дефайн вызывается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__FUNCTION__` — это не строковый литерал, который можно просто конкатенировать (типа `"a""b"`), и даже не макрос. Поэтому конструкция `"xxx"_something` воспринимается как user-defined строковый литерал, отсюда и ошибка. Исправить можно, например, так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define MESSAGE(c) #c": cannot access class member " + std::string(__FUNCTION__) + "!"

int main() {
  std::cout << MESSAGE(CTrader);
}
```

Кстати, имя `__FUNCTION__` не описано в стандарте, так что для переносимости лучше использовать `__func__` (что заодно показывает, что это не макрос).

Также можно использовать https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location.